# array creation from equation output

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to for example divide all integers from 1 to 5 by 8 and put them in an array. I was thinking something similar to the code below but I'm sure it's wrong and dirty:

```
 COUNTER=0
 until [  $COUNTER -lt 8 ]; do
        ${steps[$COUNTER]}=1+(5-1)/8*$COUNTER
        let COUNTER+=1
 done
```

Is there anyway to do this cleanly if my code is correct at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` can only do integer arithmetic. Use `bc` for floats:

```
from=1
to=5
steps=8
for c in $(seq 0 $steps) ; do
    ar[c]=$(echo $(bc -l <<< "$from + ($to - $from) / $steps * $c"))
done
echo "${ar[@]}"
```

Comment: The OP wants to divide all integers from 1 to 5 by 8 and store that in the array.

Comment: @terdon: I understood the question differently before you edited it.

Comment: I know, it really wasn't clear, hence the comment and lack of downvote :)

Comment: I get really massive values with a lot of zeros in front of them any fixes?

Comment: @RaymondGhaffarianShirazi: You can shorten the output of `bc` by declaring `scale`: `bc -l <<< "scale=3; $from +  ...`

Answer (score 2):

The `seq` command can increment by a float:

```
declare -a steps=($(seq 1 .5 5))
```

You can get the increment with `echo 'scale=1;(5-1)/8'|bc`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but since bash doesn't do floating point arithmetic, you'll need to use another tool and save its output in the bash array. For example:

```
$ perl -le 'print $_/8 for 1..5' 
0.125
0.25
0.375
0.5
0.625
```

Save in an array with:

```
array=( $(perl -le 'print $_/8 for 1..5') )
```